# excel vba runtime error 7: out of memory formula length greater than 1024

Tags: vba, excel, out-of-memory

I developed a macro where user will select criteria and I have to create formulas on selected criteria.
I am getting out of memory error 7 when formula length is greater than 1024 characters.

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(29, 4).Formula = quar_dchc_high_8_9_10
```

The length of the string `quar_dchc_high_8_9_10` is 1290 characters.
Is that creating a problem?
Formula in `quar_dchc_high_8_9_10` is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$AX$2:$AX$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$X$2:$X$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$AX$2:$AX$65536=8))+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$AX$2:$AX$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$X$2:$X$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$AX$2:$AX$65536=9))+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$AX$2:$AX$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$X$2:$X$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Jan_HC.xls]HC'!$AX$2:$AX$65536=10))+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$W$2:$W$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536=8))+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$W$2:$W$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536=9))+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$W$2:$W$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Feb_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536=10))+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$W$2:$W$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536=8))+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$W$2:$W$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536=9))+SUMPRODUCT(SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536="6G"),SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$W$2:$W$65536="Female"),SIGN('[Mar_HC.xls]HC'!$AV$2:$AV$65536=10))
```

Is the formula length greater than 1024 characters causing the error
How to solve it?

Comment: I've found following URL "https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3", please check this URL with your Excel's version.

Comment: Not sure why you rolled back the edit? I fixed the formatting as your formula was being parsed as VBA code and broken across 2 lines.

Answer (score 0):

So you must shorten the formula.

First, I see the sheet name `'[Jan_HC.xls]HC'` very often. Is it really necessary to include the reference to another workbook and sheet in your formula? If not, then remove it and you are done.

Likewise you can shorten the characters for the range `$AX$2:$AX$65536` by making it a named range, e.g. name it `ALL`.

Otherwise you could use more than one cell for the formula and have parts in each cell, being finalized in your target cell.

EDIT:

You can replace `SUMPRODUCT` with `SUM` because the arrays are just 1 value, namely the result of `SIGN` which is 1 or 0.